# Remover de uma Lista de Inteiros

Tags: java, android

Eu tenho um `ImageButton` o `imgB1`:

Quando clico no `imgB1`, adiciono a uma `list` de inteiros, 1.
Se voltar a clicar no `imagB1`, ele remove o 1 e coloca o 6.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Quando clico:

```
if (ContemLista(v) == false)
{
   list.add(1);
}
else
{
   list.remove(1);
   list.add(6);
}
```

No entanto, o número 1 continua na `list`. O que estou a fazer errado?

Answer (score 4):

O método `remove` dessa estrutura (`List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();`) tem dois parâmetros para remoção, um é do tipo `Object` e o outro é o `index` (índice) da *posição*, no seu caso parece que estava removendo uma posição que não era do valor 1 e sim do `index` 1.

Para remover poderia então ser de duas formas:

**Removendo pelo valor:**

```
lista.remove((Object)1);
```

**Removendo pelo índice da posição se encontrar:**

```
int ret = lista.indexOf(1);
if (ret > -1) lista.remove(ret);
```

Java e sua programação maluca.

<sup>***Referências:***</sup>

- [Java ArrayList indexOf() Method example](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-arraylist-indexof-method-example/)
- [Java.util.ArrayList.indexOf() Method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_indexof.htm)

Comment: Não acho sobrecarga seja algo maluco, muito pelo contrário, costuma ser bem útil em algumas situações. Um detalhes, tem um "1" sobrando  em `lista.remove((Object)1);`

Comment: @diegofm eu respeito a sua opinião, não entendi a parte do sobrando?

Comment: Erro meu, perdão, não está sobrando.

Comment: tranquilo @diegofm

Answer (score 4):

A interface `List<Integer>` do Java possui 2 métodos `remove`:

`Integer java.util.List.remove(int index)`: remove o elemento da lista no `index` (índice) especificado. Caso ele exista, o valor no `index` é retornado, caso contrário, retorna `null`;

`boolean java.util.List.remove(Object o)`: remove o objeto especificado da lista. Caso ele exista, retorna `true`, caso contrário, retorna `false`.

O método evocado sempre será o que melhor corresponde ao parâmetro passado. No seu caso, você está passando um `int`, dessa forma o método evocado é o `remove(int index)`.

Para você evocar o método `remove(Object o)`, você deve passar especificamente um `Integer` dessa forma `lista.remove(Integer.valueOf(1))`.

Código de exemplo:

```
public class RemoveFromListInteger {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add(1);
        lista.add(2);
        lista.add(3);
        lista.add(4);

        lista.remove(1);                    //Remove na posição 1, ou seja, o valor 2
        System.out.println("Depois de remover na posição 1");
        lista.forEach(System.out::println);

        lista.remove(Integer.valueOf(1));   //Remove o valor 1
        System.out.println("\n\nDepois de remover o valor 1");
        lista.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado :)

Answer (score 0):

Quando você usa o `remove` da interface `List` você passa um index pra remover como parâmetro ou o valor. No seu caso pode ser que ele tenha mais de um valor 1 na lista e se sim ele está removendo a primeira ocorrência ou então ele está removendo sempre o index 1 depende de qual método você chamou, itere seu list e faça o seguinte:

```
for (Integer num : list) {
            if (num == 1) {
                list.remove(Integer.valueOf(1));
            }
        }
    }
```

É apenas uma das opções.

Comment: Douglas, isso não funciona: `list.remove(1)` iria simplesmente remover a segunda posição da lista, cuidado com `ConcurrentModificationException` ao remover de uma lista em que você está iterando também.

Comment: Fato @AnthonyAccioly vou corrigir.